# for loop read command shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am currently working on a script that prints the directories and next to each directory the contents of that specific directory is listed and separated by a comma.

It should look like this:

- Directory: DirectoryX Files: FileA, FileB, FileC
- Directory: DirectoryY Files: FileD, FileE, FileF
- Directory: DirectoryZ Files: FileG, FileH, FileI

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash


for i in $(ls -d */)

 do 

echo "Directory:" ${i%%/} 


    echo "Files:" $(ls -m *.*) 


done
```

It lists the folders as it should do but when it comes to the files, it only lists the same two files for each folder

I also thought about putting another for loop into the for loop but I'm not sure whether it's necessary

can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You need to `cd` (or `pushd` probably better) into each dir, or prefix the dir to the `ls` inside the loop

Comment: Or pass the directory to `ls`, like: `$(ls -m -- "${i}"*)`  N.B. this is not MSDOS: * matches all files that do not start with a `.`, so no need for `*.*`.

Comment: have you considered using a tool like `tree` or is the output structure a requirement?

Comment: Avoid `for i in $(..)` pattern: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem lies in the fact that this is not MS-DOS and filenames do not necessarily contain a `.`. Use `*` to match all files.

Furthermore, there is no need to use `ls` to produce a list of all directories, `bash` can do this just fine with `*/`.

Also, `ls` does not need an argument to list all files, so this could do the trick:

```
for i in */
do
  echo -n "Directory: ${i%%/} "
  cd "$i" && { echo "Files: $(ls -m)"; cd -; }
done
```

Comment: Hi there, when I use your script Im getting something likes this:
Directory: Desktop./file10: 5: cd: can't cd to Desktop
Directory: Documents./file10: 5: cd: can't cd to Documents

file10 is the file that contains the script

any ideas what could cause this?

Thanks

Comment: I managed to change it a bit a now im getting:
- Directory: Pictures Files:
- /home/all/user

How do I get rid of the link that appears below each directory?

Comment: `ls -m` is listing all elements in the directory. If you want to display only e.g. files, you could/should use `find "$i" -type f` instead of `cd "$i" .....` (see `man find` for all the types possible)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below code which will work on Bash.

#### EDIT : Due to people sating not to parse ls, I have modified to only use find.

```
 #!/bin/bash

all_dirs=$( find ./ -type d 2>/dev/null );

while read dir
do
    files=$( find  $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//g' );
    if [ ! -z $files ]
    then
        echo "Directory : $dir - File :  $files"
    else
        echo "Directory : $dir IS EMPTY!!"
    fi
done <<< "$all_dirs"
```

Regards!

Comment: Don't use the output of `ls` or `find` like this.

Comment: here's lots of explanation about why you don't parse `ls`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I have modified.